# How to assign a right curly bracket } as attribute value inside the markup of a lightning component?

Tags: lightning-aura-components, xml, aura-attribute

In the markup of a lightning component I want to set this string a the value for a label-attribute:

`"label {1}"`

Let's take a lightning button as an example. But my question is unspecific and applies to any component and any string attribute. I also want to write it as an expression, to get the "...{1}" dynamically composed later. For the sake of simplicity I'm omitting that here.

Obviously this won't save

```
<lightning:button label="{! 'label {1}' }"  />
```

So I've tried this

```
<lightning:button label="{! 'label &#123;1&#125;' }" />
```

But still I get an FIELD_INTEGRITY_EXCEPTION error while saving:

> Cannot mix expression and literal string in attribute value, try
>   rewriting like {!'foo' + v.bar}

This will save

```
<lightning:button label="{! 'label &#123;1' }" />
```

The only remaining problem is the `&#125;` which stands for a `}` right curly bracket. The parser is obviously recognizing the closing bracket as the end of the `{!...}` expression, while I want it to be part of the value.

Is there any way to feed such a right curly bracket character into an expression of an attribute value? Is there a way to escape it somehow?

Comment: Are you evaluating the expression? if not then you dont need {!}. And can directly use : `<lightning:button label="label {1}" />`

Comment: else can you not have a string attribute and populate it via client side controller

Comment: @PranayJaiswal : yes, I need to evaluate the expression, because as said, it will become a dynamic value in the end...

Comment: @Raul : I know, but exactly this I would like to avoid

Comment: You can replace `}` with unicode `\u007D` and it is working. I just tried.

Comment: @javanoob PERFECT !!! this works. Post it as answer and I will accept it. Thanks so much!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can replace `}` with unicode `\u007D` and it is working. I just tried.

```
<lightning:button label="{! 'label {1' + '\u007D'  }" />
```

Gives the output:

[image]